# How to plot a XY graph with TimeSpan values in Calc or Excel

Tags: c#, excel, libreoffice

I'm trying to plot this data as XY in LibreOffice Calc or in Excel.

I calculate the `TimeSpan` in c#, write a csv file and open it with LibreOffice.

This is the text content (separator: `\t`):

```
age men women
17  1:41:53 1:45:36
18  1:42:43 1:46:19
19  1:40:44 1:45:31
20  1:40:09 1:52:36
21  1:38:54 1:49:52
22  1:37:48 1:53:09
23  1:38:26 1:50:41
24  1:39:22 1:51:07
25  1:37:59 1:51:56
```

When I try to plot it as XY, the labels ("men", "women") are shown but the canvas is empty. The behavior is similar in Excel.

Comment: This seems like more of an Excel or Calc question than a C# one. I guess it depends on how you define the graph? And if Excel correctly understands the type of the cells? It won't be able to plot strings. When you open the file (csv is by the way normally comma separated but I assume LibreOffice at least understands tabs and parses them by default, I don't think Excel does) do you see the values split correctly? What type do those cells have?

Comment: In Excel if I replaced the tabs with commas the file opened fine and I could do a scatter plot without any issues.

Comment: @AlexPaven The data is correctly loaded in Calc/Excel (meaning: it shows them in different columns). I've noticed that the correct Excel format for time values is to preface it with an apostrophe (`'01:14:45`). Other than that, I click on "plot XY" and the canvas is empty in both Excel and Calc. That's why I didn't discard the possibility that the root cause could be the c# string format.

Comment: No, prefixing them with an apostrophe is turning everything into text. And you can't plot text.

Comment: @AlexPaven Oh I see, that helps a lot because it's the (wrong) direction I was taking since everything else failed. [This is what I see](http://imgur.com/OeoXyZl) when I try to plot it without the apostrophe.

Comment: Check the format on a cell. Excel might not realize it's a time value, especially if it's installed in a different language that could use other delimiters apart from ':' - unfortunately Excel does a lot of things like this where it confuses raw data with UI presentation.

Comment: @AlexPaven It's frustrating because it does recognize it as a time "out of the box" ([see example](http://imgur.com/aDTXBhq)), but doesn't plot it regardless. When I try to use "format as date" with a right click etc, it puts the apostrophe in front of it.

Comment: Well that's LibreOffice which I have no experience with, it may be that it behaves differently. With Excel I didn't have any problems opening the CSV (again, with commas, tabs didn't work for me unless I imported the data manually) and plotting a scatter plot directly, no manipulation needed. I'm not sure how to tell what the issue is in LibreOffice.

Comment: @AlexPaven OK thanks. It doesn't work for me in Excel: [link](http://imgur.com/BpwxaKm). I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Ok one more time in Excel: right click on a cell and look at the format. Is it time? If it's not time, something is not right. Select time and look at what Excel expects as a time value. Maybe the language of the operating system or of the Excel instance or custom locale settings expects times to be in a weird format like '1-12-34'.

Comment: @AlexPaven This is the result (compare `NOW()` as Time, and then my custom string which is detected as text). I'm inclined to think that Excel is not acting coherently here... => [link](http://imgur.com/x3XxfZe). If I try and change my cell to "Time", it puts `'` in front of it.

Comment: That does sound very strange, but I'm not an Excel master - it's important that Excel doesn't detect times though, and that seems to be the reason. At this point I'd just look for other ways to do the same thing. What about just writing the number of seconds and plotting just numbers? Maybe you can then format the plot labels somehow to show the durations.

Comment: @AlexPaven That seems indeed the only option right now. It is even more frustrating that I've seen it work a few hours ago, but I am totally unable to find what's changed. I've just restarted just in case, with no luck either.

Comment: Maybe you'll have more luck posting the question with these additional details to https://superuser.com/